# "gibt es originelle Musik": nthuleen's rules don't match its answer sheet

Tags: grammar-identification, declension

In [the hangout](https://www.nthuleen.com/teach/grammar/adjektivendungenexpl.html) nthuleen provides about adjective declensions, it says that

[image]

But in [the worksheet](https://www.nthuleen.com/teach/grammar/adjektivendungen1antw.html), question A.4, it says

> Im Gasthof Luitpold gibt es originell**e** Musik (f).

To my understanding, the adjectives that fall into the category 1 (i.e when we answer NO to the question 1), we need to use the declensions of a masculine noun in nominative/accusative/dative/genitive position. In this case, *Musik* is in accusative - since it is a direct object - so *originell* should get ending *-en*, but instead it gets *-e* in the answer sheet - which is in fact the word-ending of a feminine word in the same position.

What is going on here?

Comment: What exactly is a "der-word"?

Comment: @DonHolgo I suppose it refers to a masculine noun

Comment: It seems that the wanted “der-word” here is “diese”.

Comment: You should know that the last time I checked there were errors in nthuleen's handling of adjective declension. Only in for the genitive and only for the "strong" declension (no article/determiner). Also, native German speakers don't use the same terminology for grammar that they teach German learners, which might explain the confusion over terms like "der word" and "ein word".

Comment: @DonHolgo: "Der" and "ein" words are names given to help learners understand German declension. A "der word" is a word which declines like "der", so "der" itself and "dieser", "welcher", "aller", etc. An "ein word" is a word which declines like "ein", so "ein" itself, possessive pronouns like "mein", also "kein". Adjectives have "weak" declension after der words, "mixed" after ein words, and "strong" if there are no such words are in front of it. (This does not include predicate adjectives.) You need to understand what these terms mean before you can follow nthuleen's method.

Comment: Please do not post text as a picture. Some handicapped people can't read text from a screen, they use programs that read the text aloud so they don't read it with their eyes, but they hear it with their ears. And this will not work when there is no text but a picture.

Comment: This question has some issues: it copies in a picture of q quoted page (quoting is good), which is subject to copyright (which is bad) , and fails to explain the essential term *der-word* in a convincing way, even considering the authors comments to other answers. I strongly recommend, to rephrase the question so it no longer requires an external reference (the quoted fragment is obviously insufficient).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, native German speakers have no clue how difficult declining adjectives is for learners. (Mark Twain, who was a serious student of German, said "Now let the candidate for the asylum try to memorize those variations, and see how soon he will be elected.") So nthuleen's approach to teaching it is to use a kind of flowchart. Her flowchart isn't the only one possible, so you'll have to forgive me if my logic doesn't match hers 100%.

The three pieces of information you need are 1) What type of word precedes the adjectives, 2) the case, 3) the gender and number of the following noun. In this case the word in front of the adjective is *es* and this is not part of the phrase. So the answer to 1) is there is nothing in front of the adjective. This means you use what is called the "strong" declension. The "strong" declension pattern has, with two annoying exceptions, the same endings as the declined versions of *der*. From the case (accusative) and the Gender (female), you get *die Musik* so the adjective gets the same ending as *die*, in other words it gets a *-e* ending.

Note, the "decline strong like *der*" rule does not work in the genitive case for masculine and neuter nouns, and the last I checked nthuleen's flowchart did not account for this. The form of *der* you'd use is *des*, but the adjective ending is *-en*. For example *Das Aroma frischen Heus ist entspannend.* The strong genitive combination is not very common, so I'm not sure if many speakers would find *Das Aroma frisches Heus ist entspannend* a noticeable error. I do remember hearing though that the *-en* ending in this case is a relatively recent change.

Comment: I can't imagine parsing _das Aroma frisches Heus_ as unnoticably correct. Maybe this can happen to speakers who have very little contact with written language (old rural dialect speakers), but never an average educated person, I'd say.

Comment: @phipsgabler: That's good to know. It's hard to make up a natural sounding example, so I've wondered how often the combination even comes up.

Answer (score 2):

"Orginelle Musik" is akkusative form. Maybe you mixed up the endings of a male word with those of a female? The image you paste has the neuter and male versions for examples (das Bier, der Kaffee).

`definitive / indefinitive form
Nom.: die orginelle Musik   / orginelle Musik
Gen.: der orginellen Musik  / orgineller Musik
Dat.: der orginellen Musik  / orgineller Musik
Akk.: die orginelle Musik   / orginelle Musik`

Please mind I use the order of cases as I got taught in school. There usually is no plural form of 'Musik'.

Comment: But the rule says that in the case where the noun has no article, you would use the word-ending of a der-word, meaning that the actual gender of the word that is being modified is irrelevant.

Comment: Not sure which rules you learn(t). Declension of male and female words is different, also in the indefinitive form. e.g. see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Deklination#Substantive

Comment: @Our no, this interpretation is wrong. The handout does not tell what a der-word is, but a demonstrative pronoun works here. For female singular it's nominative: diese, accusative: diese, dative: dieser, genitive: dieser. The same endings are used for female adjectives without an article.

Comment: @RHa so if I understood you correctly, I need to look at how "dies" is declined and use that declension with the adjective in question?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you wrote correctly, you're misinterpreting *ending on a der-word*. It does not mean ending of the masculine singular, but refers to the endings of determiners, e.g. *dies-er, dies-es, dies-e* (which doesn't work as well for the definite article itself, as the feminine form has to be interpreted as *di-e*). This gets you *originell-e Musik* as required.

In technical parlance: *der* is not intended to be understood as masculine, or as the word form *der* (which is the masculine singular form of the definite article, among others), but the [lexeme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexeme) *der*, which includes all word forms *d-er, d-(a)s, di-e* etc.

I think the term *der-word* is used because by the time learners need to acquire rules for adjective endings, they should be very familiar with the forms of the definite article. The disadvantage being minor annoyances such as *d**as** Bier, frisch**es** Bier* and *d**ie** Musik, originell**e** Musik*.

Answer (score -1):

Let's use the correct names:

In German grammar we have:

- **Artikel** (article)

  - **bestimmter Artikel** (definite article)

    > der, die, das, des, dem, den
  - **unbestimmter Artikel** (indefinite article)

    > ein, eine, eines, einer, einem, einen

This list of German articles is complete. There are just 6 defines articles (which all translate to *"the"* in English) and 6 undefined articles (in English: *"a"* or *"an"*). No other German word is an article.

- **Artikelwort** (article word) = **Determinativ** (determiner)
  These are words that can be used like an article. All articles belong to this category, but also some other words which are not articles. Both terms *Artikelwort* and *Determinativ* are valid, and so are also *Determinans, Determinierer, Determinator, Determinant, Determinante* and *Determinativum* (English names: *determiner* or *determinative*), but I prefer *Determinativ* because *Artikelwort* implies too much similarity with the articles, which can lead to misunderstandings.

---

Ein *Determinativ* (a determiner) can be:

- ein **Artikel** (an article) (definite and indefinite, as listed above)
- ein **Demonstrativpronomen** (a demonstrative pronoun)

  - Proximaldemonstrativum (proximal demonstrative) for things nearby

    > dieser, diese, dieses, diesem, diesen
  - Distaldemonstrativum (distal demonstrative) for things far away

    > jener, jene, jenes, jenem, jenen
- ein Fragedemonstrativum (interrogative demonstrative)

  - ask for identity

    > welcher, welche, welches, welchem, welchen
  - ask for quality (and identity) (the complete group of 3 words behaves as one determiner)

    > was für ein, was für eine, was für einer, was für einem, was für einen
  - ask for quantity or number

    > wie viel, wie viele, wie vielen
  - Ask for affiliation

    > wessen
- ein Possessivpronomen<sup>1</sup> (a possessive pronoun)

  > mein, meine, meines, meinem, meinen
  > dein, deine, etc.
  > sein, ihr, unser, euer etc.
- ein Indefinitpronomen (indefinite pronoun)

  > kein, keine, keines, keinem, keinen
  > jeder, jede, jedes, jedem, jeden
  > alle, aller, allen, allem
  > etliche, einige, mehrere, etc.
- sometimes (but not always) also these word behave like a determiner (they are determiners when they are used as indefinite pronouns):

  > viel, viele, vieler, etc.
  > wenig, wenige, weniger, etc.

<sup>1</sup> A possessiv pronoun is only a determiner when it is used attributive:

> **Mein** *Auto* steht in der Garage.

But you can use possessiv pronouns also in other ways, but then they are not a determiner:

> Das Auto, das in der Garage steht, ist **meines.**

---

Examples:

> **Der** kleine Mann trägt **einen** dunklen Hut. **Dieser** Hut sieht **dem** grauen Hut, der dort drüben liegt, sehr ähnlich.
> **Welchen** Hut meint du?
> Ich meine **jenen** Hut, der dort drüben auf **dem** kleinen Tischchen liegt.
> Aus **was für einem** Material ist **dieser** Hut?
> **Wie viele** Hüte besitzen Sie?
> **Wessen** Hut ist das?
> Das ist **der** Hut **meiner** Tante.
> **Euren** Hüten sieht man an, dass sie billig waren.
> Egon besitzt **keinen** Hut, ihm gefallen auch **keine** Mützen.
> **Manche** Menschen glauben ja, dass **jeder** Mann **einen** Hut haben sollte, aber nur **wenige** Männer haben tatsächlich einen.

---

So, is any word, that is connected to a noun a determiner? No, it's not!
Any adjective is not a determiner, also any participle:

> Der **kleine** Mann trägt einen **dunklen** Hut.

The words *kleine* and *dunklen* are adjectives. They describe the noun, but they do not determine it. So, you need an extra determiner, wich in both cases is an article here. The same is true for participles. They also need an additional determiner:

> Der **schlafende** Mann hat einen **gefärbten** Schnurrbart.

And this is why *viel* and *wenig* sometimes are no determines, because you also can use them as adjectives:

> 2 Adjectives: Die **vielen** Leute kaufen ein **wenig** Brot.
> 2 Determiners: **Viele** Leute kaufen **wenig** Brot.

Any Noun can have at most one determiner, but as many adjectives and participles as you want:

> wrong: *Die diese* Frau sitz an *einem meinem* Tisch.
> correct: Die *große alte blondhaarige unscheinbare* Frau sitz an einem *kleinen wackligen runden hölzernen braunen* Tisch.

---

### Null-Artikel

Sometimes you can use a noun also without a determiner. This is always the case then you want have a noun that you would use with an indefinite article, but you need it in plural:

> Singular definite: **Der** Mann schläft.
> Plural definite: **Die** Männer schlafen.
> Singular indefinite: **Ein** Mann schläft.
> Plural indefinite: ∅ Männer schlafen.

The sign ∅ shall indicate that there is an invisible determiner, the so called null-article. (Same in English: *Men are sleeping.*)
This is just another way to say that there is no determiner where you would expect one. But the concept of the null-article helps to better understand what is going on here.
If we use the null-article, wen can say, that every noun always has exactly one determiner.

And you also use the null-article for *singularia tantum.* A *singulare tantum* is a noun that exists only in singular form, i.e. there is no plural like *water, health, money* etc. You can use them in English without a determiner (*"He drinks ∅ water."*) and this is true in German too:

> Er trinkt ∅ Wasser.

But also Bier, Kaffee and Musik are singularia tantum:

> ∅ Bier schmeckt gut.
> Ich trinke gerne ∅ Kaffee.
> Im Gasthof Luitpold gibt es ∅ Musik.

Of course you can add a determinative, but it's optional:

> **Mein** Bier schmeckt gut.
> Ich trinke gerne **diesen** Kaffee.
> Im Gasthof Luitpold gibt es **viel** Musik.

And then you can add an adjective:

> Mein **deutsches** Bier schmeckt gut.
> Ich trinke gerne diesen **kalten** Kaffee.
> Im Gasthof Luitpold gibt es viel **originelle** Musik.

But you can also use the null-article as determiner. This does **NOT** turn the adjectives into determiners!

> ∅ **Deutsches** Bier schmeckt gut.
> Ich trinke gerne ∅ **kalten** Kaffee.
> Im Gasthof Luitpold gibt es ∅ **originelle** Musik.

Comment: I think part of the problem was that the person asking the question was trying to dive into adjective declension without understanding this, and you need to understand at least some of it before the rules can make sense. I'm not a fan of the term "null-article" since it assumes that the default for a noun is to have a determiner. Some languages don't use articles at all and they certainly aren't putting null-articles everywhere. I have seen the term used though, and it's a valid interpretation, like "holes" in a semiconductor, the things that aren't there whose movement carries charge.